# Using a wildcard in the path with os.path.getsize() returns error: OSError

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

```
import os

csv = "./CSV/*.csv"

os.path.getsize(csv)
```

I have 1 file under the directory /CSV that is a .csv file. I want to get the size of that file. I don't want to use the name of the file in the code because the .csv file will change regularly.
Currently returns the error:

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: './CSV/*.csv'

I've tried a few different methods, including using glob, most of the time I only manage to return the name of the file instead of the actual file itself.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you tried with `csv = "CSV/*.csv"`. and you are running parallel to CSV folder, right?

Comment: your path must be invalid, try using absolute path rather than relative path

Comment: I have tried that, yes. My working directory is one above CSV. I.e. the file is in Project/CSV/file.csv, and I am in the Project directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `glob` library

```
import os
import glob

csv_files = glob.glob('./CSV/*.csv') #THIS RETURNS A LIST EVEN IF THERE IS A SINGLE MATCH
for csv_file in csv_files:
    print(os.path.getsize(csv_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like this?

```
import os
import glob
In [68]: csv_files = glob.glob('./CSV/*.csv')
In [69]: size_obj = {}
In [70]: for file in csv_files:
    ...:     size_obj[file] = os.path.getsize(file)
    ...:
```